# Two way connections in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to make a simple console chat in Go, just to practice. However, I don't know how to send messages back from the server. The server just receives a message and then closes the connection. How could I send a response?

I have been searching and found information about websockets, but I think that they are used to interact with browsers.

This are the two functions of the server:

```
func runServer() {
    // Listen on a port
    listen, error := net.Listen("tcp", ":8272")

    // Handles eventual errors
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Listening in port 8272.")

    for {
        // Accepts connections
        con, error := listen.Accept()

        // Handles eventual errors
        if error != nil {
            fmt.Println(error)
            continue
        }

        fmt.Println("Connection accepted.")

        // Handles the connection
        go handleConnection(con)
    }
}

func handleConnection(con net.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("Handling connection.")

    var message string

    // Decodes the received message
    decoder := gob.NewDecoder(con)
    error := decoder.Decode(&message)

    // Checks for errors
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Received", message)
    }

    // Closes the connection
    con.Close()
    fmt.Println("Connection closed.")
}
```

This is the function of the client:

```
func runClient() {
    // Connects to server
    con, error := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8272")

    // Handles eventual errors
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Connected to 127.0.0.1:8272.")

    // Sends a message
    message := "Hello world"
    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(con)
    error = encoder.Encode(message)

    // Checks for errors
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
    }

    con.Close()

    fmt.Println("Message sent. Connection closed.")
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Removing `con.Close()` or at least moving it to a spot when you're done with the connection would be a good start...

Comment: But which method must I use in order to wait for a response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `con` object is a connection, which has `Read` and `Write` methods described here: [here](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn). You should loop on the connection, trying to `Read` incoming data, then process it and (possibly) `Write` back the server response. (Here, `bufferio`package and the like can help you process it in a more convenient way, this is just the low-level `ReadWriter` interface)

The documentation shows a tiny [example](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#example_Listener):

```
go func(c net.Conn) {
    // Echo all incoming data.
    io.Copy(c, c)
    // Shut down the connection.
    c.Close()
}(conn)
```

Which processes only the first message and then closes. You can process each incoming message like this:

```
go func(c net.Conn) {
    // Infinite loop: Get data, copy them and start over
    for {
        // Echo all incoming data.
        io.Copy(c, c)
    }
    // Shut down the connection.
    c.Close()
}(conn)
```

Replacing `io.Copy` with whatever is relevant to your server of course, so your example would be something like this:

```
func handleConnection(con net.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("Handling connection.")

    defer func() {
        // Closes the connection
        con.Close()
        fmt.Println("Connection closed.")
    }()

    var message string

    // Decodes the received message
    decoder := gob.NewDecoder(con)
    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(con)
    for {
        error := decoder.Decode(&message)

        // Checks for errors
        if error != nil {
            fmt.Println(error)
            // Exit the loop
            return
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Received", message)
            // Sending back
            if error = encoder.Encode(message); error != nil {
                 fmt.Println(error)
                 return
            } else {
                fmt.Println("Echo'd successfuly ! Waiting for next message...")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should probably use package `log` instead of `fmt` for your logging messages (but this is irrelevant here).

A good place to understand how it all works is to browse the implementation of the default `http` server [here](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/).

Similarly, your client should loop using the same pattern:

```
LOOP:
    Send data (e.g. encoder.Encode)
    Receive data (e.g. decoder.Decode)
    if problem or termination -> break out of loop
END
close connection
```